# function* (Generator Object) practical utility?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

> This is a new technology, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard .
> This technology's specification has been finalized, but check the
> compatibility table for usage and implementation status in various
> browsers.
>
> The function* declaration (function keyword followed by an asterisk)
> defines a generator function, which returns a Generator object.
>
> You can also define generator functions using the GeneratorFunction
> constructor and a function* expression.

**Example given:**

```
function* idMaker(){
  var index = 0;
  while(index < 3)
    yield index++;
}

var gen = idMaker();

console.log(gen.next().value); // 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
console.log(gen.next().value); // undefined
// ...
```

[MDN function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

**Question:**

While the example is understandable, why should I be using it over something like this:

```
var index = 0;
function idMaker(){
  return (index < 2) ? index++: undefined;
}
```

or even (to answer the index scope comment):

```
var idMaker = function(){
  this.index = 0;
  this.next = function(){
    var res = (this.index < 3) ? this.index++: undefined;
    return { value: res };
  };
}

var gen = new idMaker();

console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
```

Comment: That simple example is only to be used to show syntax and calling conventions. In real life, you wouldn't use a loop either, you'd just do `console.log(1, 2, 3)`… The comparison between generators/loops is flawed in this case, but I hope my answer to the duplicate is more useful.

Comment: Generators make it very easy to create iterators :)